# redis install: unsupported locale setting

Tags: redis

I am trying to install redis [like here](http://redis.io/download). But when do `make`, got error unsupported locale setting:

```
# make
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.3.1 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
Exception information:

unsupported locale setting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 24, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 69, in main
    enable_i18n()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 40, in enable_i18n
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/locale.py", line 541, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: edited my answer. eye it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install all the locals

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-id
```

and then configure

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

then try again.

Ok configure them manually .

paste these lines one after one

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Done. The same error.

Comment: manual configuration was successfull. Thank you

Comment: @efr glad to hear that.